# Weird double click behavior with text highlighting, when dynamically changing the contentedible attribute of a div

Tags: javascript, focus, mouseevent, contenteditable

The requirements:

1. We need an editable div that only becomes editable after a user clicks on it
2. The div goes back to being read-only when focus is taken away from the div

The issue:

- I can achieve these 2 requirements with no issues, however I get unideal text highlighting behaviour, namely when double clicking
- We expect that a single click when the div is not editable makes the div become editable. A click after this should set a selection in the div. However, if these two clicks happen too quickly, the second click is treated like its a double click - highlighting an entire word wheras only a selection shouldve been made. I don't know how to correct this behaviour.

What I've tried:

- Simply using css, with user-select=none doesn't work
- Perhaps need to preventDefault the mousedown event, and manually call .focus() on the div, but this approach has its difficulties in putting the caret in the right position

Demo Code:

The HTML is just a simple contenteditable div, with contenteditable initially as false (read-only). My real code is done with slatejs, but the issue can be demonstrated here

```
<div contenteditable="false">
  initial text
</div>
```

Some styling to make it nicer to differentiate between the read-only state and editable state

```
[contenteditable] {
  border: 6px solid #333;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  outline: none;
  min-height: 1em;
}

[contenteditable="false"] {
  border-color: rgb(238, 192, 192);
  color: #aaa;
  user-select: none;
}

[contenteditable="true"] {
  border-color: green;
  color: black;
}
```

The basic js to achieve the 2 requirements as stated:

```
const editor = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]');

let hasFocus = false;
function setHasFocus(newFocus) {
    editor.setAttribute('contenteditable', newFocus);
  hasFocus = newFocus;
}

editor.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (!hasFocus) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setHasFocus(true);
  }
})

document.addEventListener('mousedown', () => setHasFocus(false));
```

In sandbox:
https://jsfiddle.net/bv93sLn6/30/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue essentially occurs in the browser inaccurately assuming the click count is higher than it should be. I solved it by keeping a store of the previous `range`, and replacing the current range with the previous if need be.

Sandbox: https://jsfiddle.net/2gvxrf3y/56/

Answer (score 0):

You can remove that text selection by addition double click event listener. On that double click listener, we can remove the text selection.

```
editor.addEventListener('dblclick', e => {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(editor);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
})
```

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jegatheesprana/uyrs5v9z/) code

Comment: This won't work. 
Unfortunately, we still want the click event to happen - just not to be registered as a double click.

Comment: Register this double click event listener along with the mouse down event listener.

Comment: I have added a js fiddle code in my answer.

Comment: Again, this won't work. I'm not trying to kill double clicks completely. The issue at the beginning when the user is selecting the text for the first time, and it highlights all text when it shouldn't have. I still want normal behaviour with highlighitng.